# A problem occurred evaluating project ':device_info_plus' (issue in flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

After updating the flutter version to 3.10.3 I have updated the package_info_plus pkg to 4.0.2 version. After this build is failing.

the exact error showing is **No signature of method: build_1mupxig66s099lwbohzx15wgm.android() is applicable for argument types**.

***Other details***

distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.1-bin.zip

Comment: I guess you already tried, but the first step should be to do a `flutter clean` followed by a `flutter pub get`

Comment: Yes I did this already

Answer (score 17):

As they mentioned on package's changelog since [v4.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus/changelog#400), Flutter project must be Android Gradle Plugin > 4.2

> BREAKING FIX(all): Add support of namespace property to support
> Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8 (#1727). Projects with AGP < 4.2 are not
> supported anymore. It is highly recommended to update at least to AGP
> 7.0 or newer.

So, to solve this, you need to update your AGP classPath dependency at `android/build.gradle` with

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`

and you need to update distributionUrl at `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` with

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip`

Comment: Why is this comment not awarded as the correct answer?